# Is there any queue method in Angular 7 equivalent to c# queue?

Tags: angular, angular7, typescript2.0

I need to take queue my data from response and retrieve it from other end.
Is there method in angular 7 to get it done?

Comment: Are you searching for a queue data structure implementation for Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own queue class

```
class Queue<T>{
 _queue: T[];

 constructor(queue?: T[]) {
  this._queue = queue || [];
 }

 enqueue(item: T) {
  this._queue.push(item);
 }

 dequeue(): T {
  return this._queue.shift();
 }

 clear() {
  this._queue = [];
 }

 get count(): number {
  return this._queue.length;
 }
}
```

Comment: I need to dequeue all the data from the list. Is shift() will return only the first value, Is there any way to get the whole data and remove it from the array.

Comment: If you need to use the values, you could dequeue in a loop until empty. If you don't need to use the values, call the clear() method.

Answer (score 0):

A Queue in JavaScript can be implemented easilly as follows:

```
var queue = [];
queue.push(2);         // queue is now [2]
queue.push(5);         // queue is now [2, 5]
var i = queue.shift(); // queue is now [5]
alert(i);              // displays 2
```